# Загрузка фото в java

Tags: java, swing

Пишу java desktop (netbeans ). Но к сожалению не могу найти вариант загрузки фото с сохранением пропорций(размер фото разный). И как загрузить фото в полный размер (разместить ее на форме) с полосами прокрутки? Буду признателен если кто-нить откликнется. Время поджимает, а вариант за неделю так и не нашел.
Нужно что то типа этого:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот один из вариантов(:

```
jFileChooser1.showOpenDialog(this);
File file2 = jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile();
BufferedImage image=null;
try {
    image=ImageIO.read(file2);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(NewApplication.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
int hl= image.getHeight();
int wl= image.getWidth();
int hi ;
int wi;
hi=hl;
wi=wl;
Icon icon;
icon = new
ImageIcon(image.getScaledInstance(wi, hi, BufferedImage.SCALE_DEFAULT));
jLabel6.prepareImage(image, this);
jLabel6.setIcon((icon));
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Кратко: вместо `.add(myJPanel);` - `.add(new JScrollPane(myJPanel));`. Здесь подробнее: https://javaswing.wordpress.com/2009/08/04/jscrollpane_using/. А что имеется ввиду под загрузкой с сохранением пропорций? Файл грузится как есть. Если нужна обработка, её нужно производить после получения содержимого файла.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказочку. ) Это нужно  jLabel присваивать размер картинки,  jLabel должна быть на JPanel на которой должен быть JScrollPane? Я правильно понимаю? Подскажите плз...

Comment: Разобрался большое спасибо))))))) Может кто подскажет как масштабировать скролом мыши?????